# filter custom post in rest api with custom function

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, filters, rest-api

i have 3 custom post type : artists, songs, videos
songs and videos have a meta that sort *artist id* of songs or videos
filter in rest api couldn't return filtered post by artist id custom meta

so i have to return that by custom function and show it in rest api

how create a function that compare value of artist id meta and return post that have specific artist id ?

something like this : */wp-json/wp/v2/songs?artist=4438*
that return songs that meta value of artist is 4438

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I mean you need to query by your custom taxonomy (eg. `songs_categories`, or whatever you named it in your `register_taxonomy()` function) and then by the term.

`&filter[taxonomy]=songs_categories&filter[term]=artist`

PS: In my context I filter via custom filter, a plugin that enhance the API. You find all information on [the repo](https://github.com/bueltge/wp-rest-api-filter-items).